# 2nd character drop cap?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I use InDesign 4.  I do a lengthy quarterly journal for a non-profit.  I always start my articles with a drop cap, but now I have one that begins with a open quotation mark.  Is there any way to leave that small and "drop cap" the first actual letter (the 2nd character)?

Comment: Typography-wise I would enlarge both the quotation mark and the first letter

Answer (score 1):

When I've seen this happen in books, I've seen the quotation mark included in the drop cap (so two characters). Otherwise the quote mark becomes invisible. If you're determined, though, I would remove it from your main text frame and set it in its own frame individually in the margin.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain — I recently had the same dilemma — after several frustrating hours and a lot of web searching I settled on this solution:
use a paragraph style with 2 nested character styles

Example explanation {you can use your own choice of "paragraph" & 'character' style names - these are the ones I used):

"Drop Cap Quote2" (paragraph style)
**drop cap:** lines = 2 (or however many you want) / characters = 2 / styles = none
*(The character styles can be predefined or created through the add new style section of this submenu.)*
**nested styles:** (add new style) 'DropCap-Quote' [through] [1] [characters] /
(add new style) 'DropCap-Letter' [through] [1] [letters]

'DropCap-Quote' (character style)
*(these settings will probably need some adjustment - use whatever looks good to the font you are using)*

- add a bit of positive tracking > +10 or so
- {Advanced Character Formats} Horizontal scale = 73% / vertical scale = 75% / Base Line shift +6

'DropCap-Letter' (character style)
*(set this character to the font size & leading that you are using for the rest of the paragraph text - you can set this character to be bold or a colour as well)*
- add positive tracking > +75 or so

It takes a bit to setup - but once done it should save you a lot of time.

HG